# Dynamic variable in javascript push function

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm using push function in javascript.

```
var chartData = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {

    chartData.push({

        date: new Date(year_s,mon_s,date_s,hr_s,min_s,sec_s),
        visits: chartData1[selection[i]][j].value,
        customBullet: show_annotations,
        balloonTextField: "testtesttest"
    });

}
```

I need to pass a dynamic variable like visits_1, visits_2, etc,. in place of visits variable in the above code. I have tried visits+"_"+i. But it is not working. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there is no JSON in the code shown (JS objects and JSON are different things).

Comment: And this isn't really a problem of *variable* but of *property*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make it in two steps :

```
var chartData = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   // 1. create the object
   var d =  { 
      date: new Date(year_s,mon_s,date_s,hr_s,min_s,sec_s),
      customBullet: show_annotations,
      balloonTextField: "testtesttest"
   };
   // 2. then assign the visits_i property
   d['visits_'+i] = chartData1[selection[i]][j].value; 
   chartData.push(d);
}
```