# Append object and property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, push

In JavaScript, how can I push an object to an array, along with some other new property. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<T_ARRAY.length; i++)
{
   if(!T_ARRAY[i].isCorrect)
   {
      NEW_ARRAY.push({T_ARRAY[i], 'idxPerg' : i+1});
   }    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable in javascript push function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977733/dynamic-variable-in-javascript-push-function)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the property by doing something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<T_ARRAY.length; i++)
{
   if(!T_ARRAY[i].isCorrect)
   {
       var newObj = T_ARRAY[i];
       newObj.idxPerg = i+1;
       NEW_ARRAY.push(newObj);
   }    
}
```

Also you can use the dynamic key notation

```
for(var i=0; i<T_ARRAY.length; i++)
{
   if(!T_ARRAY[i].isCorrect)
   {
       var newObj = T_ARRAY[i];
       newObj["idxPerg"] = i+1;
       NEW_ARRAY.push(newObj);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have any syntax which adds a property to an object and returns the original object. You have to do it in two statements.

```
T_ARRAY[i].idxPerg = i+1;
NEW_ARRAY.push(T_ARRAY[i]);
```