# How do I split two strings and make a key-value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object, split, literals

```
var ma = "jim";     
var nu = "123";    
var splitit = ma.split("");    
var splitit2 = nu.split("");    
for (i=0; i<=splitit.length;i++) {
    var bach = {splitit[i]:splitit2[i]};
}
alert(bach);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable in javascript push function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977733/dynamic-variable-in-javascript-push-function)

Comment: Initializing variables inside of the for loop is not a good strategy for performance. It is better to cache it outside the loop and make reference to it. Please note.

Comment: @gabeno I don't see why they could be a difference (variable declarations are hoisted) and tests don't support your thesis either : http://jsperf.com/var-in-for-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
var bach = {}; // create the object
for (i=0; i<=splitit.length;i++) {
    bach[splitit[i]]=splitit2[i]; // set a property according to the arrays
}
```

instead of

```
for (i=0; i<=splitit.length;i++) {
    var bach = {splitit[i]:splitit2[i]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var ma = "jim";     
var nu = "123";    
var splitit = ma.split("");    
var splitit2 = nu.split("");    
var bach = {};
for (i=0; i<=splitit.length;i++) {
    bach[splitit[i]] =splitit2[i];
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nHvSL/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables for property names in object literals, they always get interpreted literally. And you probably want only one `bach` object, instead of creating a new one each loop turn.

```
var bach = {};
for (i=0; i<=splitit.length;i++) {
    bach[splitit[i]] = splitit2[i];
}
alert(JSON.stringify(bach));
```